# Forever stops logging after deleting the log file

Tags: node.js, logging, npm, forever

I'm running a NodeJS script using forever npm package. As the log size grew large in size, I made a backup of the file and deleted it assuming that the forever could re-generate the log file and start writing logs into it. But it didn't create the log file. Then I tried to create a log file with the same name hoping that the forever script would then start writing the logs to it. Though the file has the same permissions like the file before, it still didn't write anything into it.

How can I make forever write to the log files without restarting the script? Should any changes be done to the config file? Or am I missing something?

NodeJS version: 0.8.16 Forever version: 0.15.2

Comment: Node *0.8.16*?! That's from 2012 - I'd recommend switching to a version that's still supported (6.9.1 is the current long term support version) to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @JoeClay Would not solve this problem which requires the problem to be solved without restarting the script.

I don't think you can solve this without restarting the script. I assume forever only checks for the files existence at startup, then never again. If you are not getting any errors in your console, I assume it silently fails subsequent tries to write things to the log file.

Comment: @Stian so there's no possibility of solving this without restarting the script?

Comment: @JoeClay the script has been running for more than 3+ years. the problem i have is not upgrading the node version. but making forever continue to print logs to a file. i'm very sure that, just restarting the script would solve the issue. but can't afford to do that as it would disconnect all clients immediately.

Comment: @santhgates well if forever js haven't accounted for something like this, I very much doubt there is anything else to do than restart the script.